# Recent top tags in Tumblr blog

Tags: javascript, jquery

A friend of mine asked me to write a script for showing the most used tags in her Tumblr blog in the last days. I saw it as a great opportunity for learning JavaScript and accepted it, as it seemed simple enough while being useful.

I "chose" the requirements to be:

- Simple basic usage, not requiring JavaScript knowledge to modify the output (CSS only);
- Fetches the last `N` posts, or all posts up to `N` days ago, or both (whichever comes first);
- As a side use case, someone could be interested in "which tags did I use the most in a given period of time?", but in this case some Javascript could be needed.

I also tried to not use any existing library, however I had a problem with [cross-domain requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request), and found on the web that jQuery would help me with the JSONP protocol, which the [Tumblr REST API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) does implement, and opted to use jQuery in the script. Aside from that, I've written the documentation as jsdoc comments. I also avoided the most recent ECMA6(?) implementations, as it seems most modern browsers do not support it.

```js
/**
 * Display your recently most used tags in your Tumblr blog.
 * Requires jQuery.
 * @see getTags
 * @see display
 * @namespace
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @example
 * RecentTags.getTags({
 *   blog: 'example.tumblr.com',
 *   maxTags: 5,
 *   maxPosts: 100
 * }, function(data) {
 *   RecentTags.display(data, '#top-tag-div', 'top-tags', null);
 * });
 */
var RecentTags = RecentTags || {
    
    /**
     * @typedef GetTagsInput
     * @type {Object}
     * @property {String} blog - Blog name
     * @property {Number} maxTags - Amount of tags to collect
     * @property {Number} [maxDays] - Look for posts up to maxDays ago. Either maxDays or maxPosts is required
     * @property {Number} [maxPosts] - Look for this amount of posts. Either maxDays or maxPosts is required
     * @property {Date} [date] - Date to consider "today". Useful for looking tag usage of a specific month
     */
    
    /**
     * Gets the recent tag usage as a pair array.
     * @public
     * @function
     * @memberof RecentTags
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @param {GetTagsInput} opt
     * @param callback - Request callback when the operation is done
     * @returns {Array} Array of pairs, the first value of the pair being the tag name, and the second the usage count
     */
    getTags: function (opt, callback) {
        var validDays = typeof opt.maxDays === 'number' && opt.maxDays > 0;
        var validPosts = typeof opt.maxPosts === 'number' && opt.maxPosts > 0;
        
        if(!validDays && !validPosts)
            return null;
        
        var posts = validPosts ? opt.maxPosts : -1;
        
        var currentDate;
        var targetDate;
        if(validDays) {
            currentDate = typeof opt.date === 'undefined' || opt.date == null ? new Date() : opt.date;
            targetDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),
                currentDate.getMonth(),
                currentDate.getDate() - opt.maxDays);
        } else {
            currentDate = null;
            targetDate = null;
        }
        this.fetch(opt.blog, opt.maxTags, opt.maxDays, posts,
            currentDate, targetDate, 0, {}, callback);
    },
    
    /**
     * Continuously fetches posts, and reduces to desired output when either stop condition is fulfilled.
     * @private
     * @function
     * @memberof RecentTags
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    fetch: function (blog, tags, days, posts, currentDate, targetDate, offset, data, callback) {
        var limit = posts >= 20 || posts < 0 ? 20 : posts;
        
        if (limit == 0 || (currentDate != null && currentDate < targetDate)) {
            callback(RecentTags.sanitize(data, tags));
        } else {
            this.getPosts(blog, offset, limit, function(resp) {
                resp.response.posts.forEach(function(post) {
                    post.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
                        data[tag] = (data[tag] || 0) + 1;
                    });
                    var dat = new Date(post.date);
                    if(currentDate > dat) {
                        currentDate = dat;
                    }
                });
                var length = resp.response.posts.length;
                if (length > 0) {
                    RecentTags.fetch(blog, tags, days, posts - length,
                        currentDate, targetDate, offset + length, data, callback);
                } else {
                    callback(RecentTags.sanitize(data, tags));
                }
            });
        }
    },
    
    /**
     * Transforms object data into a pair array, sorted and sliced to wanted tag count.
     * @private
     * @function
     * @memberof RecentTags
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    sanitize: function (data, tagCount) {
        return $.map(data, function(value, key) {
            return [[key, value]];
        }).sort(function(a, b) {
            if(a[1] < b[1]) return 1;
            if(a[1] > b[1]) return -1;
            return 0;
        }).slice(0, tagCount);
    },
    
    /**
     * Transforms the tag usage data in either a Html <ul> ou <table> tag.
     * All tags will have a class according to the prefix, following:
     * table => prefix-table,
     * tr    => prefix-row,
     * td    => prefix-td,
     * ul    => prefix-list,
     * li    => prefix-item
     * @public
     * @function
     * @memberof RecentTags
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @param {Array} data - array of pairs, result of a {@link getTags} call
     * @param {String} selector - selector for the element(s) to put the created element
     * @param {String} prefix - defines class of created elements
     * @param concatenator - If null, a table is created. Otherwise, the tag and count are given to it, and the result is a list item
     */
    display: function (data, selector, prefix, concatenator) {
        if(typeof concatenator === 'undefined' || concatenator == null) {
            this.displayTable(data, selector, prefix);
        } else {
            this.displayList(data, selector, prefix, concatenator);
        }
    },
    
    /**
     * Displays in table format
     * @private
     * @function
     * @memberof RecentTags
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    displayTable: function (data, selector, prefix) {
        var table = $('<table class="' + prefix + '-table"></table>');
        var elements = data.map(function(pair) {
            return '<tr class="' + prefix + '-row">'
                + '<td class="' + prefix + '-name">' + pair[0] + '</td>'
                + '<td class="' + prefix + '-count">' + pair[1] + '</td></tr>'
        });
        table.append(elements.join(''));
        $(selector).append(table);
    },
    
    /**
     * Displays in list format
     * @private
     * @function
     * @memberof RecentTags
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    displayList: function (data, selector, prefix, concatenator) {
        var list = $('<ul class="' + prefix + '-list"></ul>');
        var elements = data.map(function(pair) {
            return '<li class="' + prefix + '-item">' + concatenator(pair[0], pair[1]) + '</li>';
        });
        list.append(elements.join(''));
        $(selector).append(list);
    },
    
    /**
     * Sends a request to the Tumblr API
     * @private
     * @function
     * @memberof RecentTags
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    getPosts: function (blog, offset, limit, callback) {
        var url = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/' + blog +
            '/posts?offset=' + offset + '&limit=' + limit +
            '&callback=?';
        
        $.getJSON(url, callback);
    }
    
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        RecentTags.getTags({
          blog: 'example.tumblr.com',
          maxTags: 5,
          maxPosts: 100
          }, function(data) {
            RecentTags.display(data, '#top-tag-div', 'top-tags', null);
          });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      .top-tags-table {
        color: #FF0000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top-tag-div">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As I said, this is my first time with JavaScript (and web develop in general) outside a tutorial, so really any advice is appreciated. Especially, is it common to write unit tests for such IO/GUI heavy scripts? Is it ok for a script to assume a given library (jQuery in this case) is already imported from the HTML page? I've seen the `require` statement, but it seems specific to NodeJS implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's bust some myths:

### ES2015 is not supported in all major browsers

I will use ES2015 (commonly known as ES6) in my answer. Everything I tell you is supported by the latest stable version of Chrome and Firefox. Also, I'm fairly certain that most of the features I'll discuss have support in several versions back of Chrome and Firefox.

It's worth noting that most of the features are **not** supported in IE, so if you absolutely must have it, use a polyfill or older tech (i.e. `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch`).

### I need jQuery for JSONP requests

No, you do not. JSONP is a hack to get around the API author's decision to not supply CORS headers (For whatever reason). So JSONP wraps the response with a function call (of your choosing; **[example](https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/david.tumblr.com/avatar/512?callback=jsonpHandler)**), so it becomes valid JavaScript code. Then all you do is append the code to the DOM with a `<script>` element, and your function is called:

```
// Fetch API is relatively new. So not supported by IE.
// This can easily be a regular XMLHttpRequest as well.
fetch(`${apiUrlWithParameters}&callback=jsonpHandler`) // faulty, if no prior params
  .then(response => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = response;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }); // Also, handle errors with `.catch()`

function jsonpHandler(data) {
    // Handle the response here
}
```

See the **[fetch API for more details.](https://devdocs.io/dom/fetch_api)**

### I need jQuery for collection iteration

No, you do not.

Mapping over arrays is easy. `someArray.map(mappingFunction)`
Mapping over objects is also quite easy. `Object.keys(someObject).map(key => /* key is the key. someObject[key] is the value. */)`

### I need jQuery for this other thing

No, you do not.

Unless you need *older browser support* (Older = IE8 and below), you almost certainly do **not** need jQuery as a hard dependency.

---

Great, now that we got that out of the way, in no particular order:

- Your `fetch` function has far too many arguments, it's hard to keep track. Consider passing an options object just like you've done with `getTags`.
- It isn't clear what `pair[0]` and `pair[1]` are. Give more descriptive names:

  ```
  let key = pair[0];
  let value = pair[1];
  ```
- [Template strings are pretty cool](https://devdocs.io/javascript/template_strings) and supported in Edge too!
- Your `display` function can basically be shortened to `return concatinator ? this.displayList(...) : this.displayTable(...);`
- What's the point of turning your nice key: value object into an array of arrays? It makes it less descriptive and less readable (also, less debuggable), while providing no real profit.
- This

  ```
  post.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
      data[tag] = (data[tag] || 0) + 1;
  });
  ```

  Smells like you wanted to use [`reduce()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/reduce).
- It looks to me you only want to reveal the `getTags` and `display` functions from your module. Have a look at the **[Revealing Module Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)** to only reveal the methods you want exposed.
- When providing with an options object argument, a good practice to follow is to have a `defaults` object defined in the function, and then have the passed `options` object [assigned](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/object/assign) to it.

  ```
  function(options /*, ... */) {
      let defaults = {
          maxTags: 10,
          maxPosts: 100,
      };
      Object.assign(defaults, options); // options will override defaults
      // snip
  ```
- If required parameters of the options object are missing, you should **throw an error** (in your example, the `blog` field appears to be rather important.
- `typeof whatever === 'undefined'` should only be used if you aren't sure anyone ever defined `whatever`, in the case of `obj.whatever`, if you know obj is defined (which it is, because it's `this` most of the times in your code), just use `this.whatever === undefined`.
- `typeof opt.maxDays === 'number'` this check is redundant and misleading. `opt.maxDays` may be `NaN` and the check will pass. The `> 0` check is sufficient.
- Always use `===`. ***ALWAYS***.
- Your `fetch` function mutates the `data` parameter passed to it. It means that the following is not true:

  ```
  var myData = { ... }; // whatever
  this.fetch(/* whatever */, myData);
  // myData here is the same as before the fetch.
  ```

  That's dangerous. Create new objects inside functions and return them. Mutating passed objects is mud you don't want to get into.
- `resp.response` It's either that `resp` is the response, or `response` is. In either case, one of them should be changed.